# Apex (Salesforce) read json from response and store it in a string variable

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code, salesforce-lightning, aura-framework

I am trying to hit a API endpoint which is responding something like below when I am calling 
response.getBody()

{
 "oktaToken": "eyJraWQiOiIyNlN1NHFMNnVVZTVJX2M5X2Z3WmZvX09ON0dNUHRtQzlEeHFsTGplLS00IiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYifQ.eyJ2ZXIiOjEsImp0aSI6IkFULlVINmdIOF9BcWJ"
}

Now I wanted to store the value of this token into a string variable.

response.getbody() is already a string but I want the value to be stored in a String variable. I don't wanted to do any manipulation in the String (response.getbody()) like splitting & substring.

Is there something using json parsing so That I can get the value of token in a variable by passing the key('oktaToken')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String jsonStr = '{ "oktaToken":"eyJraWQiOiIyNlN1NHFMNnVVZTVJX2M5X2Z3WmZvX09ON0dNUHRtQzlEeHFsTGplLS00IiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYifQ.eyJ2ZXIiOjEsImp0aSI6IkFULlVINmdIOF9BcWJ" }';
Map<String, String> m = (Map<String, String>) JSON.deserialize(jsonStr, Map<String, String>.class);
String oktaToken = m.get('oktaToken');
System.debug(oktaToken);
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

[JSON.parse(string)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) will use the input string to create an object, and it's properties can then be accessed using dot notation.

So in your case, you could do something like:

```
var responseBody = JSON.parse(response.getBody());
var oktaToken = responseBody.oktaToken;
```

Comment: It needs to be deserialized & then assigned to a String variable, the syntax is quite different & i tried that but it's not recognizing the oktaToken. Something like below: LigClass obj = (LigClass)JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), LigClass.class);